# Not being able to override external scss file with !important tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I've been trying to build a page that has external SCSS files. I was having no trouble overriding specific elements with !important until now. I know this question is popular here. I've gone through

This answer
[How to override external css marked as !important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323252/how-to-override-external-css-marked-as-important) ,

this
[How to override external css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828327/how-to-override-external-css)

this
[How to overwrite SCSS variables when compiling to CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089717/how-to-overwrite-scss-variables-when-compiling-to-css)

and some other, but none of them seem to work for my case.

My goal is to set a change of colors of my boxes through CSS @keyframe timer (or any other method that can work), BUT there's a color rule set as !important in a external SCSS file.
I was able to override it once by also adding a !important in MY local css, to get to the base color I wanted, but the color change seems not to work and not be able to override those two !important s, even with higher specificity and so on.
I'll provide the parts of the code that are important for this question:

Theme styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="box2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://shipping.mambo.com.br/shipping-store/views/_includes/dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
```

The box I'm using:

```
<div href="#" id="boxMaster" class="small-box bg-info" class="box-PEDIDO" tabindex="0">
      <a class="nmroPedido small-box-header" id="header" href="#"></a> <a class="float-right" id="dataEntrega"></a>
      <hr>

      <div class="inner">
        <p id="nomeproduto"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon">
        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="carrinho"></i>
      </div>
      <hr id="footer" class="baixoHr" tabindex="-1">
      <a class="small-box-footer" tabindex="-1">   

      </a>
    </div>
```

and my local CSS:

```
     .row .info-box .info-box-icon {
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer; 
    
    height: 115px;
    width: 30px;
  }
   .box-PEDIDO {
    height: 135px;
    width: 423px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .card-title {
    font-weight: bolder;
  }
  
  

  

  .row {
  height: max-content;
}


hr#antigo {
  border: 0;
  height: 25px;
  background: #333;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc, rgb(0, 0, 0), #ccc);
}







/* NOVO */


body #preparando .small-box  {
  width: 423px;
  height: 160px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 11px;
  
}

 html body div #preparando .small-box {
  background-color: var(--bs-success) !important;
}




#preparando:focus-within .small-box:focus-within {
  background-color: #29923f !important;
}

#prontos .small-box {
  width: 423px !important;
  height: 160px !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 11px;
  background-color: var(--bs-dark) !important;

}
 
.small-box-footer {
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 423px !important;
  text-align: right !important;
  margin-right: 5px !important;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 250 !important;
  background: none !important;
  cursor: default;
  
  
}

 h3 {
  font-size: 1.2rem !important;
  font-weight: lighter !important;
  
}

.h3qtd {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -37px !important;
  margin-left: 10px !important;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.3rem !important;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  height: 90px;
  margin-top: 4px !important;
  position: absolute;top: 65px;
  width: 250px;
  line-height: 27px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  font-weight:500;
}

.inner {
  height: 42px;
  margin-top: -30px;  /*Altura da "quantidade", ajustar dps*/
}

#header {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro",-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  height: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  display: inline-block;
}

#dataEntrega {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.small-box .icon > i {
  position:absolute; top: 50px !important;
}




hr {
  position: relative; bottom: -9px !important;
  width: 423px !important;
}

.baixoHr {
  position: relative; top: 74px;
}

.nroPedHead {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  
}


.nmroPedido-0 {
 margin-top: -72px !important;
 position: absolute !important;
 margin-left: 5px;
 font-size: 0.75rem;
  
}

.float-right {
  margin-top: -71px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
     
}



#preparando div .small-box .bginfo {
    animation: change 10s step-end both !important;
}

@keyframes change {
    to   { background-color: var(--bs-warning) !important }
}
```

where the important parts lie in `html body div #preparando .small-box { background-color: var(--bs-success) !important; }` (where it works even without all that specification)

and the most bottom part

```
#preparando div .small-box .bginfo {
    animation: change 10s step-end both !important;
}

@keyframes change {
    to   { background-color: var(--bs-warning) !important }
}
```

Note: the color change keyframes work for other elements in the page, but is NOT able to change the color of the box.

How can I make it work? Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** MRadev 's answer does work and triggers the color change, with every element BUT .bg-info (which is the background of the box), because of that !important in external CSS file I believe.

Still trying to find a way to work around that.
Set MRadev's lines to each element won't work because of the remainders of green from .bg-info background that bleeds through the colors of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the !important statement that is embeded inside of a key. "!important" inside of keyframe is ignored. Please refer to:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes#!important_in_a_keyframe

And

https://rules.sonarsource.com/css/RSPEC-4655

This shouldnt be the problem you want to solve, but rather the need to use !important. Usually that would mean you have a badly structured styles. (I do get what you are trying to do with the overwriting the library.

Maybe your best solution would be using JS animations instead of the CSS ones in your case. Or maybe think in another direction and avoid the animation all together as your example works perfectly if you do not use the animation, but overwrite the "background-color" directly and as mentioned in the upper answer - have your "!important" be loaded first so the library one is ignored.

Shown here with your code:

```
// Smallbox:
.small-box > .inner {
    animation: change 2s step-end both;
}

// Outher box
.bg-info {
 background-color: yellow !important;
}

@keyframes change {
    to   { background-color: red}
}


@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/admin-lte@3.1/dist/css/adminlte.min.css")
```

https://codepen.io/Rbx/pen/zYdrvRP?editors=1100

Comment: Oh I see. Your answer DOES work @MRadev, in parts. Your answer was able to apply the Red color keyframe in .inner, that paints a chunk of the top part of the box. The .bg-info Yellow Background-color did not, though. 
But with your implementations, I'll try to make some adjustments to your contribution and see if I can make that apply for the whole box. I'll leave the question open so if I can work around that I update it.

Comment: I am glad it helps in some way. The main idea is that the current idea is not supposed to work. About the implementation it is only meant to show the specificity (in the small-box part) and that the .bg-info part just shows that !important works as expected when applied first :)

Comment: I might be missing somenthing... The .bg-info part doesn't work, at all. No matter how I change things or how specific I am.

If I put .bg-info instead of ".inner" in the first line, it also does nothing. 
I understand that your ideia was to demonstrate, and it did. But I'm still confused on why I can't do a thing about .bg-info.

Comment: In the example the .bg-info is overwritten with an yellow background and its done by the one way I can think of right now (will edit if I get an idea). But have this in mind:
1. The .bg-info cannot be changed trough the first line since you cannot put !important inside the keyframes and 2. adding !important to the value of the animation does not actually overwrite the background declaration -> therefore you cannot overwrite the !important of the library. The example shows that you need to directly use the background-color !important and put it BEFORE loading the lib. (It is not a solution)

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with libraries using !important in their styles; it is very hard to be overridden. It would be impossible for the browser to assume which !important tag is more important than another !important tag, so it just takes the first one. The only way to do this is to make your style targeting more specific than the library.

For instance, if the library is setting !important on an element based on class name, then you can use an ID target in your CSS to make it "more specific" (IDs are supposed to only be set on a single element, so it is considered the most specific form of targeting).

The only other way to override a third party !important tag is to make sure your CSS loads first with its own !important tag on that particular style. Then when the library styles load, it won't be able to override yours.

An example in code:

```
html body div #preparando .small-box { // This is targeted by class name
     background-color: var(--bs-success) !important;
}

html body div #preparando .small-box#someID { // This is targeted by ID which is more specific
     background-color: var(--bs-success) !important;
}
```

Comment: I see. In the part you use as example, the style DOES work and IS applied when !important is added. The part that I can't solve is the color change at the bottom of the CSS.
There, it doesn't. The color change is never applied, even with specifications and !important (tried with the specification path you just answered. Did not work.)

Comment: Did you change the specificity on the keyframes? or on the #preparando div .small-box .bginfo targeting?

Comment: ` html body div #preparando .small-box#boxMaster {
    animation: change 10s step-end both !important;
}

@keyframes change {
    to   { background-color: var(--bs-warning) !important }
}`

I changed it at the keyframe animation declaration. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that should have worked. W3 schools has a write up about this that explains it here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp. I will see if I can whip up an example of your code and see why it isn't working a little later.